# Checkbox is not displaying in rows from ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, checkbox

I created list view with check box at column 1, but it's displaying only at header level and in rows i'm getting namespace name.

Here's the XAML code:

```
        <ListView x:Name="ConfigurationFilesGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding ConfigurationFiles}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProgramFile}"
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                  PreviewMouseDoubleClick="ConfigurationFilesGrid_Reselect"
                  >
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=ConfigurationMainCtrl, Path=DataContext.IsAllConfigurationSelected}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.IDColNameTxt}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.TypeColHdr}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DisplayType}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.NameColNameTxt}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.MeterColNameTxt}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding MeterType}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.RateColNameTxt}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RateDisplay}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.CommentColNameTxt}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Comment}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.ModifiedDateColNameTxt}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ModifiedDateTime}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="{x:Static res:Resources.ProfileColNameTxt}" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Profile}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

And i'm getting list view like:

```
[](checkbox)  ID   Name   Address
  name        1     A       X
  name        2     B       Y
```

But from above i'm getting checkbox only at header level not rows level so what change 'll reflect to checkbox from above xaml code.

Thanks for you help.

Nag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used the `HeaderTemplate` of the `GridViewColumn`, use the `CellTemplate` instead:

```
<GridViewColumn>
   <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=ConfigurationMainCtrl, Path=DataContext.IsAllConfigurationSelected}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: But by declaring this i'm not getting checkbox in the column header which is required to select all.

Comment: Use both HeaderTemplate and CellTemplate to get both.